# What does Beta badge mean?

Tags: discussion, badges

The badge description says "Actively participated in the private beta", but I suppose there's an exact criterion - what is it?

Also - it says "*private* beta". The current status is "beta", and it doesn't seem very private to me - so the badge refers to an earlier stage?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, found two links that have to do with this:

[When do I earn the Beta badge](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/81833/when-do-i-earn-the-beta-badge)

[Why are beta badges awarded at all?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86/why-are-beta-badges-awarded-at-all)

Answer (score 2):

Yes - the "Beta" badge refers to the private beta stage - the first 7 days of the site's life after it completed the commitment phase.

I'm not 100% sure of the criteria for getting the badge, but you have a number of posts and votes. There have been similar questions on another sites' meta, but I can't remember which one so I can't post the link.

Comment: it's not counted on votes but purely # of posts during private beta.